# how to right-align a nested div in all major browsers?

Tags: html, css

I just have a top nav of a website. I want to float a div to the right for User Login controls etc.
I looked on the web and tried but it does not work in Chrome / Firefox.

What is the EXACT way to do this correctly in ALL browsers using Divs and CSS? WHat I have works only in IE 9 .. Chrome and Firefox both drop the loginControls Div down to the next line.

```
<div id="topNav">
    <div id="logoBar">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/header_logo.gif" width="132" height="50" border="0" /></a>

        <div id="loginControls">User: John Doe &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Logout</a></div>

    </div>
    <div id="navTabs">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>

#logoBar {
    width: 1300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(../images/line.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding: 0px 22px;
    position: relative;
}

#navTabs {
    background-color: #333b52;
    height: 30px;
}

#loginControls {
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 250px;
}

#loginControls a:link, #loginControls a:visited, #loginControls a:active {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: You say you want to float a container yet float isn't anywhere in your css. That's odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add

```
float : right;
```

In `#loginControls`' CSS

Comment: No dice :) It does not change anything.

Comment: Try giving a separate div for <a>  and img tag with float : right;

Answer (score 2):

The person who answered just add float is correct as long as you remove the absolute positioning.

```css
#logoBar {
    width: 1300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(../images/line.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding: 0px 22px;
    position: relative;
}

#navTabs {
    background-color: #333b52;
    height: 30px;
}

#loginControls {
    float:right
}

#loginControls a:link, #loginControls a:visited, #loginControls a:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="topNav">
    <div id="logoBar">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/header_logo.gif" width="132" height="50" border="0" /></a>

        <div id="loginControls">User: John Doe &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Logout</a></div>

    </div>
    <div id="navTabs">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ty, works in Mozilla browsers but now IE9 has dropped it below the main div.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of a div is to always use 100% of the width of the parent Container. 
you may have to try span instead of div for the Login Controls.

OR use float:

```
#LoginControls {
    float:right;
    width: 250px;
}
```

I can't test it yet but I hope Im right. ;)

**Edit: Ok someone was faster then my but did you try span?**

Comment: Changing div to span is the same as adding display:inline to the css for a div. So trying span instead of div is not correct.

Comment: oh ok. I doesn't know that :)